# Laravel check if belongstomany contains belongstomany

Tags: php, laravel, collections, relationship

in my system:

- a lead belongstomany salespeople
- a manager belongstomany salespeople

i am trying to check if a lead has a manager through the salespeople. this is for a policy so i can make sure a manager can see the leads of their salespeople.

something like this:

```
$lead->salespeople->contains($manager->salespeople)
```

is there a collection method that will allow me to do this? i've also tried stuff like this which isn't working either:

```
$lead->salespeople->contains('id', $manager->salespeople->pluck('id')->toArray())
```

edit, i think i got it. does this look correct?:

```
$lead->salespeople->intersect($manager->salespeople)->count() > 0
```

Comment: `a manager belongstomany salespeople`. you sure? Ideally `Manager hasMany SalesPerson`. One salesperson cannot(should not) have many managers.

Comment: Try to achieve this in query instead of collection. It will be more efficient esp. when data is huge.

Comment: There is a `hasManyThrough` relationship in Laravel, check this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this problem with this package: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Here's my relationship method now:

```
public function managers()
{
    return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->salespeople(), (new User)->setAlias('salesperson')->managers());
}
```